# how to implement JBPM with Spring+ jpa and custom UI (like vaadin) for Human task?

Tags: spring, jpa, jbpm

i want to use **Vaadin ui**  to interact with **human task** assigned to a particular user in the process. i am also using **jpa** for persistance and **spring** for creating beans like taskService,ksesion,kbase etc...!! i also need help on how to use business domain on a particular  node to update,insert or delete data.

Comment: Did you resolved your problem?

Comment: not yet @svlada ,i am still strugling to implement JBPM with Spring and JPA, later i will look at how to implement same with Vaadin just like this demo(https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Building+Vaadin+Applications+on+top+of+Activiti)

Comment: I have managed to implement JBPM to work with Spring and JPA. Basic Human task start and complete.